# Finding and replacing a numeric string between colons, before a space, using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I am attempting to change all coordinate information in a fastq file to zeros. My input file is composed of millions of entries in the following repeating 4-line structure:

```
@HWI-SV007:140:C173GACXX:6:2215:16030:89299 1:N:0:CAGATC
GATTACAGATTACAGATTACAGATTACAGATTACAGATTACAGATTACAGATTACAG  
+              
@@@FFFDFHGGDHIIHGIJJJJJJJJJJJGIJJJJJJJIIIDHGHIGIJJIIIJJIJ
```

I would like to replace the two numeric strings in the first line `16030:89299` with zeros in a generic way, such that any numeric string between the colons, before the space, is replaced. I would like the output to appear as follows, replacing the two strings globally throughout the file with zeros:

```
@HWI-SV007:140:C173GACXX:6:2215:0:0 1:N:0:CAGATC
GATTACAGATTACAGATTACAGATTACAGATTACAGATTACAGATTACAGATTACAG  
+              
@@@FFFDFHGGDHIIHGIJJJJJJJJJJJGIJJJJJJJIIIDHGHIGIJJIIIJJIJ
```

I am attempting to do this using the following sed:

```
sed 's/:^[0-9]+$:^[0-9]+$\s/:0:0 /g'
```

However, this does not behave as expected.

Comment: I don't know SED but does the `^` not mean the start of the string there? and likewise the `$` the end? Again not knowing SED i think you'd want `:[0-9]+?:`

Comment: Does it has to be sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to use `sed -r` option.
Also, `^` matches beginning of the line and `$` matches end of the line. 
Thus this is the command line that works against your sample.

```
sed  -r 's/:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\s/:0:0 /g'
```

Comment: `$` matches end of the string, one that can also be of multiple lines. `\n` matches end of the line, no?

Answer (score 0):

some alternative

```
awk -F ":" 'BEGIN{ OFS = ":" }{ if ( NF > 1 ) {$6 = 0; sub( /^[0-9]*/, 0, $7)}; print $0 }' YourFile
```

using column separate by `:`

```
sed 's/^\(\([^:]*:\)\{5\}\)[^[:blank:]]*/\10:0/' YourFile
```

using 5 first element separate by `:` thant space as delimiter

for your sed

```
sed 's/:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\(\s\)/:0:0\1/'
```

- `^`and `$` are relative to the whole string not the current word
- option to keep the original space instead of replacing by a blank space (case of several or other like `\t`)
- `g` is not needed (and better not to use here) because normaly only 1 occurence per line
- you need to be sure that the pattern is not possible somewhere else (never a space after the previous number) because it's a *small* one